# Terminal and backstab hybrid?

Tags: receptacle

While dismantling an outlet to be replaced I noticed I had the two usual hot and neutral wires that were screwed in with the terminal and then I noticed an extra hot and neutral wire back stabbed into that same outlet. I keep seeing things about not using backstabs because they are the inferior connection. Is it common to have a hybrid? Can I not just keep the extra disconnected and cap them off?

Comment: what extra ? there are no extras, they do something

Comment: Is it a backstab, or is it merely "screw-and-clamp connected" to the back? There's a huge difference. If the wire comes out when you undo the side-screw associated with it, it's screw and clamp. If it stays stuck in its hole, it's a backstab with the spring-loaded contacts.

Comment: Please [edit] in pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Backstabs are not the best connection.

What you have with that outlet, is one set to provide power and two sets to go somewhere else, other outlets/lights.

Before doing anything turn off the breaker and double check there is no power at the outlet.

What you can do, is remove the black from the screw and backstab, and with a wire nut connect the two with a short black, which is called a *pigtail*. The new short will then go onto the screw. Repeat with the whites.

Comment: +1 for pigtails. No backstab, never more than one wire under a screw.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a modern variation of the backstab where the wire is clamped between two plates by the screw rather than by a spring; I believe these are reliable, and they're almost as convenient as backstabs were.

(They don't take pulling strain as well as a wire hooked around the screw will, but connections at the outlet should have strain relief clamps or staples or whatever so that issue shouldn't arise.)

Answer (score 0):

Back stabs are generaly not considered reliable connection.

However there are a variation of back stabs designs to make them more reliable.

Single one sided spring loaded contact and dual sided spring loaded contacts (which is better).

In order to prevent screwing two wires with same screws (not recommended), they use the back stab for the second connection which might be ok, pending the back stab type.

Yes, you can disconnect them and then find out what is not working.

Comment: They are known to catch on fire and/or melt because they are unreliable and cause arcing. *If* they are actually backstabs (poke and pray spring-loaded) at all.

Comment: @Ecnerwal internet stories, UL still proves them ? but only for #14 gauge

Comment: "internet stories" Are you saying you don't believe @ecnerwals assertion that backstabs are "unreliable and cause arcing"? Just earlier this year, I had to diagnose a loss of power in one room of a house, which would occasionally briefly work again. Traced it back to an outlet that used backstabs, had to cut several inches of wire back as the insulation was compromised from heat. I would not trust backstabs even for #14 gauge.

Comment: @GlenYates was it single or dual spring contact